# Dynamic Key JSON Deserialization not working

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a JSON data as given below

```
{
  "openingTimes": {
    "general": {
      "monday": [{
        "opens": "09:00",
        "closes": "18:00"
      }],
      "tuesday": [{
        "opens": "09:00",
        "closes": "18:00"
      }],
      "wednesday": [{
        "opens": "09:00",
        "closes": "18:00"
      }],
      "thursday": [{
        "opens": "09:00",
        "closes": "18:00"
      }],
      "friday": [{
        "opens": "09:00",
        "closes": "18:00"
      }],
      "saturday": [],
      "sunday": []
    },
    "alterations": {
      "2012-12-31": [{
        "opens": "09:00",
        "closes": "12:30"
      }, {
        "opens": "13:30",
        "closes": "18:00"
      }],
      "2012-12-24": [{
        "opens": "09:00",
        "closes": "12:30"
      }, {
        "opens": "13:30",
        "closes": "18:00"
      }],
      "2012-12-25": [],
      "2012-12-26": []
    }
  }
}
```

I have created the classes like below:

```
public class OpeningTimes
{
    public OpeningGeneral General { get; set; }
    public OpeningAlterations Alterations { get; set; }
}

public class OpeningGeneral
{
    public List<Hours> Sunday { get; set; }
    public List<Hours> Monday { get; set; }
    public List<Hours> Tuesday { get; set; }
    public List<Hours> Wednesday { get; set; }
    public List<Hours> Thursday { get; set; }
    public List<Hours> Friday { get; set; }
    public List<Hours> Saturday { get; set; }
}

public class Hours
{
    public string Opens { get; set; }
    public string Closes { get; set; }
}

public class OpeningAlterations
{
    //**UNABLE TO DESIGN**
}
```

Can you please suggest how the class OpeningAlterations should be coded?

Comment: So that after Serializing the class I can get back the original JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from searching the web, I can suggest you to use `Dictionary` instead of your `OpeningAlterations` class.

Your dictionary should look like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, Hours[]> Alterations { get; set; }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a Dictionary with an object array such as this

```
public class OpeningTimes
{
    public OpeningGeneral General { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Alteration[]> Alterations { get; set; }
}

public class Alteration
{
    public string Opens { get; set; }
    public string Closes { get; set; }
}
```